# Submitting a large file using subprocess check_all in parallel

Tags: python, arrays, parallel-processing, subprocess

I have a code which compromises of making an input file and submitting it to an executable using subprocess.check_all. Unfortunately the process is too slow. The input file size usually tends to be larger than few hundred megabytes.

I was wondering if its useful to write the input file in binary and run the subprocess in parallel.

```
input_xyz = open(initial + "_xyz.inp", "w")
input_xyz.write("{0:d}\n".format(length**3))
for ix in np.linspace(xmin, xmax, length, True):
    for iy in np.linspace(ymin, ymax, length, True):
        for iz in np.linspace(zmin, zmax, length, True):
            input_xyz.write("{0:12.6f} {1:12.6f} {2:12.6f}\n".format(ix, iy, iz))
input_xyz.close()

subprocess.check_call(["elec_pot_calc", initial + ".tvb", initial + ".csx",
        initial + "_xyz.inp", initial + "_xyz.out"])
```

The input is a set of xyzzy files with a header which is the number of inputs

```
1000
  -10.403406   -12.484424   -16.060428
```

and output will be the same with an added number calculated in the executable

```
1000
    -10.4034060000000004     -12.4844240000000006     -16.0604280000000017       0.0008508183029086
```

Comment: Does `elec_pot_calc` require the input to be a text file as the one you generate? What in the process is slow? Do you know that the IO is what limits your performance?

Comment: most of the computation time is the "elec_pot_calc". but generating the text file can turn slightly costly too as it tends to get very large at some points. yes it to be input to be text.

Comment: So, how would you then go about to get the file to the process? Pipe it in there? It seems like a minimal gain, at best. You would probably be better served by creating a RAM disk that you write to and read from.